# What do the paranthesis and $ sign mean in echo $(ls)

Tags: command-line, bash

The output of

```
# ls
```

and

```
# echo $(ls)
```

are the same.  What exactly does the $ sign and the parenthesis mean?

Also, what is going on a technical level that causes the output of these two commands to be the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is command substitution for bash.

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
>   command itself. Command substitution occurs when a command is enclosed
>   as follows:
>
> ```
>  $(command) or
>
>  `command`
> ```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

More:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst

And a good example similar to your question:

http://bashshell.net/shell-scripts/using-command-substitution-in-a-bash-shell-script/

Answer (score 3):

When the shell encounters text enclosed in `$(` `)`, it:

1. Takes it to be a command and (as [Panther says](https://askubuntu.com/a/85003/22949)) runs the command in a [subshell](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell).
2. Substitutes the *output* of the command, in place of the entire `$(...)` expression. Any trailing [newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) are removed from this output.
3. Performs further expansions if `$(...)` was not [quoted](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) (see below).

As [heartsmagic's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/85005/22949) explains, this is [one of two available syntaxes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) for [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

### *"What ... causes the output of these two commands to be the same?"*

It's actually somewhat uncommon for the output of `ls` to be *exactly* the same as the output of `echo $(ls)`:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ ls
bar  foo
ek@Io:~/tmp$ echo $(ls)
bar foo
```

[`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/ls.1.html) typically separates filenames by two or more spaces, or a newline. This helps us tell them apart more easily, especially since spaces in filenames are somewhat common (but multiple consecutive spaces, less common).

### Word Splitting

When I ran `echo $(ls)`, the following happened.

1. [**Command substitution**](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) replaced `$(ls)` with:

   ```
   bar
   foo
   ```

   You might be surprised to hear that, since that's probably not what you see when you run `ls` by itself! This disparity in what `ls` outputs is explained below, but is actually not the reason you end up with a single space between those two words. The same thing would happen if `$(ls)` were substituted with `bar  foo` (with two spaces).
2. Afterwards, the shell performed [**word splitting**](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting), treating `bar` and `foo` as separate [arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) to the `echo` command instead of as a single argument containing spaces.

   [Globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) (a.k.a. filename/pathname expansion) would also be performed, if the command's output had contained `*`, `?`, or `[`.

   As detailed below, [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) with [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) permits command substitution but suppresses word splitting and globbing.

When [`echo`](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) receives multiple arguments (except for options like `-n`, which are treated specially and not printed at all), it prints them all out, with a single space between subsequent arguments. `echo` then prints a newline, unless the `-n` option was passed.

Thus `echo $(ls)` shows output like `bar foo` instead of `bar  foo`.

If you run `ls` and it lists no files, or just one file, the output of `ls` will *often* be the same as the output of `echo $(ls)`. Even then, it will not always be the same, such as when a filename contains whitespace other than isolated (single) spaces:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp2$ touch 'my   file'
ek@Io:~/tmp2$ ls
my   file
ek@Io:~/tmp2$ echo $(ls)
my file
```

When `ls` prints multiple files, its output is not likely to be exactly that same as the output of `$(ls)`. Similarly:

- `echo a b` and `echo $(echo a b)` produce the same output, *but*
- `echo 'a   b'` and `echo $(echo 'a   b')` do not.

This is an important thing to know about command substitution--**unquoted command substitutions are subject to word splitting (and globbing)**.

### Quoting

If you want to prevent [word splitting](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)--and you usually *will* want to prevent them--you can enclose your expression for command substitution in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) (`"` `"`). The reason to use double quotes rather than single quotes is that single quotes are even stronger; they would suppress command substitution.

This also applies to [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), which is a more commonly used [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) than command substitution, and to [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion). The reasons it is important to quote command substitutions (except in the fairly uncommon) case that you *know* you want further expansions to occur) are the same as [the reasons to quote parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells).

### Terminal Detection

Double-quoting often sufficient to avoid unexpected results from command substitution. In particular, it will work with the `echo`-based examples above as well as the example of `ls` on a directory with a single entry containing spaces:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp2$ echo "$(ls)"
my   file
```

However, as noted above, you might be surprised to find that what you see when you run `ls` is often not what gets passed to `echo` in place of `"$(ls)"`:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ ls
bar  foo
ek@Io:~/tmp$ echo "$(ls)"
bar
foo
```

This is because `ls` checks if [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is a terminal [to decide how to format its output](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#General-output-formatting), when output formatting is not explicitly specified.

- When stdout is a terminal, `ls` outputs in vertically sorted columns, like `ls -C`.
- When stdout is not a terminal, `ls` lists each entry on its own line, like `ls -1`.

In command substitution, standard output isn't a terminal because the command's output is not being sent directly to a terminal for you to see--instead, it is being captured by the shell and used as part of another command.

To get multi-column formatting when running `ls` via command substitution, pass it the `-C` flag:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ echo "$(ls -C)"
bar  foo
```

(`dir` is sometimes suggested as an alternative to `ls -C` and [will also work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands) for this, though [`dir` behaves like `ls -C -b` rather than merely `ls -C`](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#dir-invocation).)

### Shell Aliasing

Another reason `ls` may sometimes behave differently from `echo "$(ls)"` is that `ls` may be [a shell alias](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases). Run `alias ls` to check; on Ubuntu you usually get `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`. This makes it so that, when `ls` appears as the first word of a command you run interactively (and also in the far less common situation that alias expansion has been enabled in a non-interactive shell), it is replaced with `ls --color=auto`.

For example, when I run `ls`, it lists directories colored blue and executables colored green (and observes many other coloring rules, too). `--color=auto` causes `ls` to print colored output when standard output is a terminal, and not otherwise.

To get colored output when running `ls` via command substitution, [pass it the `--color` or `--color=always` option](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#General-output-formatting). If you like, you can combine this with `-C`:

```
echo $(ls -C --color)
```

Note that while you can make `ls` an alias to `ls --color` or `ls --color=always` instead of `ls --color=auto`, and `ls --color=always` doesn't care if standard output is a terminal... that alias will still not cause `ls` to produce colored output when invoked by command substitution. This is because shell aliases (in [Bourne-style shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell_compatible) like [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))) are only expanded when the shell sees them as the first word of a command, and they are not inherited by subshells.

Answer (score 1):

`()` and `$()` are used to run commands in a subshell.

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html for details.

Answer (score -1):

Using $ in front of a variable name invokes the value assigned to the variable. Echo without the $ will just print the name of the variable to the screen (or standard out).

Comment: `(ls)` is not a variable name.