# Difference between 'dir' and 'ls' terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, directory, ls, coreutils

I've been trying to find the difference between using the `dir` and `ls` commands in terminal. I know `ls` is the traditional UNIX method of viewing the files in a directory, and that `dir` is the windows command prompt equivalent, but both commands work in terminal.

If I type in `dir`, it displays the files and folders in the directory, and if I type `ls`, it does the same, except with content highlighting. Both commands accept options (i.e. `ls -a` and `dir -a` both return all files and folders and hidden files.

So does anyone know what the difference is and why both `dir` and `ls` are used?

Comment: `dir --color` ;)

Comment: just wanted to say I'm surprised at the amount of response this question has received. I guess I was not the only one wondering about this :)

Comment: Commands from ancient times always drag the older nerds out of the woodwork ;)

Comment: [What's the difference between "dir" and "ls"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50377/44425)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`dir` and `ls` are part of [`coreutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) and `dir` is almost the same as `ls`, just with different default options.

> The GNU Core Utilities are the basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities of the GNU operating system. These are the core utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system.

`info dir` says:

> `dir` is equivalent to `ls -C -b`; that is, by default files are listed
>   in columns, sorted vertically, and special characters are represented
>   by backslash escape sequences.

Oh and there is also `vdir`! `info vdir` says:

> `vdir` is equivalent to `ls -l -b`; that is, by default files are
>   listed in long format and special characters are represented by
>   backslash escape sequences.

Most likely `dir` exists for backwards compatibility or due to historical reasons.

Comment: I was thinking that it was probably just an alias of the other. I assumed the reasoning was to make windows users feel more at home lol Thank you for the thorough answer!

Comment: type `alias dir` to see what it actually is. type `alias` to see all aliases.

Comment: @user606723 , 'alias dir' doesn't show in 11.10 (at least not for me). I believe 'alias' only shows local user alias settings, not system wide.

Comment: type `type dir` to see what it is (an alias, a command, a bash function...)

Answer (score 76):

### The Relationship Between `ls` and `dir`

`ls` and `dir` are separate programs that behave similarly. As explained and referenced below, **the purpose of `dir` is to provide a command like `ls` whose output does not vary depending on whether or not it is going to a terminal**. To achieve this helpfully, `dir` must format its output in a way that is reasonable and useful both for viewing in a terminal and for writing to a file or pipe.

There are two common misconceptions about `dir`:

- Many people believe `dir` is an alias of `ls`, but that is not the case. Neither command is an alias of the other, and by default in Ubuntu, `dir` is not an alias at all. `ls` and `dir` are provided by separate, non-identical executables.
- Many people believe `dir` exists for obscure historical reasons or to provide compatibility with some standard or some other OS. That is not the case either. *`ls` behaves the way it does for compatibilty.* `dir`, which doesn't have to be compatible because it's not a standard Unix command, behaves in an alternate way that the developers consider valuable in its own right and possibly even preferable.

### OK, but exactly how do `ls` and `dir` differ?

Both `ls` and `dir` list the contents of directories. Two specific differences in their default behaviors distinguish them.

1. When its [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is a terminal, `ls` lists filenames in vertically sorted columns (like `ls -C`). When its standard output is not a terminal (for example, a file or [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)), `ls` lists filenames one per line (like `ls -1`).

   Whether or not its standard output is a terminal, `dir` lists filenames in vertically sorted columns (like `ls -C`).

   For both `ls` and `dir`, these defaults may be overridden by the `--format=` flag and by the `-1`, `-C`, `-m`, and `-x` flags, which abbreviate particular `--format=` options. See [10.1.4 General output formatting](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#General-output-formatting) in the [GNU coreutils reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/) for details.
2. When its standard output is a terminal and a filename to be listed contains [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), `ls` prints `?` instead of each control character (like `ls -q`). When its standard output is not a terminal, `ls` prints control characters as-is (like `ls --show-control-chars`).

   Whether or not its standard output is a terminal, when `dir` encounters a control character or any other character that would be interpreted specially if entered into a shell, it prints backslash sequences for the characters. This includes even relatively common characters like spaces. For example, `dir` will list an entry called `Documents backups` as `Documents\ backups`. This is like `ls -b`.

   For both `ls` and `dir`, these defaults may be overridden by the flags listed in [10.1.7 Formatting the file names](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Formatting-the-file-names) in the [GNU coreutils reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/). This includes `-b`, `-q`, `--quoting-style=`, and some others.

**Sources**: [ls invocation](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#ls-invocation) and [dir invocation](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#dir-invocation), in the [GNU coreutils reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/).

### Why have `dir`?

The rationale for a separate `dir` utility is given in [4.5 Standards for Interfaces Generally](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#User-Interfaces) of the [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/). I recommend reading that whole section to understand the developers' reasoning, but here are the highlights as applicable to `ls`/`dir`:

> Please don’t make the behavior of a utility depend on the name used to
>   invoke it***....***
>
> Instead, use a run time option or a compilation switch or both to
>   select among the alternate behaviors***....***
>
> Likewise, please don’t make the behavior of a command-line program
>   depend on the type of output device***....***
>
> Compatibility requires certain programs to depend on the type of
>   output device. It would be disastrous if `ls` or `sh` did not do so in
>   the way all users expect. In some of these cases, we supplement the
>   program with a preferred alternate version that does not depend on the
>   output device type. For example, we provide a `dir` program much like
>   `ls` except that its default output format is always multi-column
>   format.

The GNU Project considers it undesirable, from a technical perspective, for a utility to produce different output depending on what kind of device it is writing to (at least in the utility's default configuration). For some utilities, including `ls`, device-dependent output is necessary for compatibility and so it works the way users expect. Some users do also specifically prefer this device-dependent behavior.

While `ls` could not reasonably be written to behave device independently, a separate `dir` utility was created to achieve this. Thus `dir` is not the utility that behaves strangely for reasons of historical compatibility--**`ls` is**.

<sup>To see how `ls`, `dir`, and the related `vdir` utility are implemented in the coreutils source code without needless code duplication, see [`ls-dir.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/coreutils/vivid/view/head:/src/ls-dir.c), [`ls-ls.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/coreutils/vivid/view/head:/src/ls-ls.c), [`ls-vdir.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/coreutils/vivid/view/head:/src/ls-vdir.c), [`ls.h`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/coreutils/vivid/view/head:/src/ls.h), and [`ls.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/coreutils/vivid/view/head:/src/ls.c).</sup>

### Is `dir` really useful?

If you've ever wished `ls` produced multi-column output even when you piped it to `less` (`ls | less`) or redirected it to a file (`ls > out.txt`), you can use `dir` or `ls -C`.

If you've ever wished you could **directly copy a filename shown by `ls` and use it as part of a command without worrying about quoting**, you can use `dir` or `ls -b`.

`dir` is equivalent to `ls -Cb`, so in that sense you don't need `dir`. But `dir` provides a combination of options that in practice is often useful (though not widely known about).

### Why do I get colorized output from `ls` (even `ls -Cb`) but not `dir`?!

Most Ubuntu users have an alias called `ls` which runs `ls --color=auto`. When `ls` exists both as an alias and an external command, the alias takes precedence in simple, interactive commands.

<sup>Alias definitions aren't expanded recursively--it's the external `ls` command that the `ls` alias is calling with `--color=auto`. See [6.6 Aliases](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) in the [Bash reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) for more information on how aliases work.</sup>

When passed to `ls`, `dir`, or `vdir` (and some other commands, like `grep`), `--color=auto` uses color when its output is a terminal, but not otherwise.

By default in Ubuntu, user accounts are created with this in `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

You'll notice the `ls` alias (`alias ls='ls --color=auto'`) is uncommented, while those for `dir` and `vdir` are commented out with `#` so they take no effect. That is, **while `dir` is not an alias, *`ls` is* (but not to `dir`)**.

### How do I make `dir` produce colored output, too?

To enable colored output with `dir`, simply edit `.bashrc` in your home directory and uncomment the `#alias dir='dir --color=auto'` line by removing the leading `#`. In shells started after the change, `dir` will be an alias.

<sup>If you want the change in the current shell, you can run the alias definition as a command, or you can source `.bashrc` by running `. ~/.bashrc`.</sup>

This arguably goes against the main point of `dir`--that it should produce the same sort of output regardless of the output device. However:

- If you find it useful to make this `dir` alias, you should certainly do so.
- When called as an external command, for example in scripts or if you override the alias by running `\dir` or `command dir`, `dir` will still produce device-independent output. This is to say that aliasing `dir` to `dir --color=auto` does not really break `dir`.

Comment: Quality answer, but could use a ToC or TL;DR;   :)

Comment: This is an excellent, very informative answer (+1), but I think you're over-reaching when you say "dir is not the utility that behaves strangely for reasons of historical compatibility--ls is." Perhaps you could say that `ls` from GNU Coreutils behaves the way it does is for compatibility with other distributions, but not just historically; many *current* users find it useful for `ls` to change its output depending on the device it's writing to, and continue to parse the output of `ls` in scripts, despite the fact that many programmers consider that to be poor form.

Comment: It  is an amazing answer..

Answer (score 5):

> I would be inclined to think that `dir` is there just [for backwards
>   compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands).
>
> From [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dir-invocation.html#dir-invocation):
>
> > dir is equivalent to ls -C -b; that is, by default files are listed in columns, sorted vertically, and special characters are represented
> >     by backslash escape sequences.
>
> By the way, `ls` doesn't colorize the output by default: this is
>   because most distros alias `ls` to `ls --color=auto` in
>   `/etc/profile.d`. For a test, type `unalias ls` then try `ls`: it will
>   be colorless.

Source: [Renan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/15630/renan)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50379/11938) to [What's the difference between “dir” and “ls”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50377/whats-the-difference-between-dir-and-ls)?

Comment: Although [`dir` is *not* provided for backwards compatibility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50377/whats-the-difference-between-dir-and-ls/50379#comment335032_50379)--and [`ls` actually *is*](https://askubuntu.com/a/615946/22949)--this answer (and the answer it quotes from) does correctly state the technical difference between the two commands as well as explaining the commonly observed colorization difference. So +1.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer : None,
`dir` is the same source code than `ls`, `ls` binary have `--color` by default. (1 line of code diff)

Comment: `dir` is **not** an alias of `ls`. They are separate binaries in `/usr/bin` that behave differently, as described in [Rinzwind](http://askubuntu.com/a/103917/22949)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/103917/22949). You could achieve this with aliases, but that is *not* how it is achieved. Separate `dir` and `ls` binaries appear on all systems that use [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#dir-invocation). If you need proof, run `cmp /bin/ls /bin/dir`.

Comment: some time ago it was an alias and you could see it listed in the alias list just by typing `alias`, now a new binary is compiled for dir. You can download its code with: `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils`.
Only one line of code is changed in ls-dir.c and is this: `int ls_mode = LS_MULTI_COL;`. Technically is not an alias, but practically it is LS but with different default options(1 line of code).

Comment: Yes, *`dir` is `ls` but with different default options*. `dir` and `ls` have always been separate binaries in distributions that use GNU Coreutils. Some distributions may, or may have, *also* defined an alias called `dir` (defining aliases that are the same name as an existing command is pretty common). But they are separate executables. To distinguish between a shell alias (which is not a file at all) and a separate executable with similar source code, is not a pedantic distinction. It is both false and misleading to say that `dir` is an alias of `ls` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but in this case, is not similar source code, is the same source code. If we say that an alias is just anything listed in `alias` then of course is not an alias.

Comment: It is not the same source code. As you said, "one line of source is changed." And if it were the same source then it would still not be an alias. There are lots of things in a Unix-like system that are *similar* to aliases but which would be vastly confusing to novices (and exasperating to experienced users) to call aliases. Symbolic links, hard links, identical files, similar files, wrapper scripts, shell builtins hiding executables, and synced files (e.g. with UbuntuOne) are all similar to aliases in significant ways, but they aren't aliases.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, compare `type ls` vs `type dir` (see also [Difference between ls and la](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863528/whats-the-difference-between-ls-and-la-why-do-they-give-the-same-output/863626#863626)):

```
$ type dir
dir is aliased to `ls -l'

$ type ls
ls is aliased to `_ls'

$ type _ls
_ls is a function
_ls ()
{
    local IFS=' ';
    command ls $LS_OPTIONS ${1+"$@"}
}
$ echo command ls $LS_OPTIONS ${1+"$@"}
command ls -N --color=tty -T 0
```

The difference boils down to different options to `ls`, in my case `--color=tty` would be the most visible, your system may differ.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a default Ubuntu user configuration at all. I don't think any of the Ubuntu systems I've used have have had `ls` as an alias for a function called `_ls` -- not even as a commented-out line in `.bashrc`. It does seem like the default for (at least some versions of) openSuSE, though, judging by [this conversation](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-_ls-4175517042/), [this file](https://github.com/openSUSE/aaa_base/blob/master/files/etc/profile.d/ls.bash) (linked from there), and my (admittedly perhaps wrong) memory of when I last used openSUSE.

Comment: @EliahKagan: You guessed it, I'm using OpenSuse! So as I said, the result will differ, but the method should be all right.