# Malware in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: malware

This is the situation I'm dealing with:

I plugged my USB in my laptop, then I created a folder within it, and nautilus stopped working for a while, I unplugged the USB and plugged back in, BUT this time there was 2 folders created, I have no access to anyone of them from Ubuntu, not even starting nautilus as root, the only way to see the files is in a Virtual Machine using Windows XP.

When accessing the folder via Terminal and typing "dir" within the folder it'll show this:

```
'\002.,\001#           \r\003aåa█ÿj."σ╗      ë.öaa           n..              SG∩▄ç@uΣ.\n╟*          αpeZ╔╤c≥.τ╬╣
(.\006\004         ░\ ^¢\027(åc.└½╜      \004▄eöqw\004ç.f╔ê  n.0              sg_≈¬\023m½.┼≥═        α:\016└P[z╛.E█\023
*.\t               a.e           ependenc.y>└zA.1ì¡
\001               ═æ┴e≤t\024ó.½s╪       ▄èqƒid╚╦.╦▐²        n'\017¼▀!τ╝.$T⌡      -Sk\036\ ε░ƒ.█²\026        Γ]euy╢╒╗.╦ê\016
\001               \020æ[f\001┤╥ä.╔\n=   \të¬╣r(¢w.b\021z    n.3              \t.SO              Γ≥G▄\037z1s.\004ßå
\001               ⁿ\fæ√]╜g%.\016îH      essorArc.hit        n/7ûöα.\002.·&ε      \t.SO              \035■\017╤Γºa╞.*åt
\001               ∞\b█$æ╬ô\002.₧╤√      essorArc.hit        n.a              s.R                ╟≡┤ΓXJ₧P.\037zk
\001               Æ,┐_ôs\026ε.\021\016\b    estedPri.vil        ndalone=."ye         ⁿ▄ß≤\026¬è%.¡û¬        ├:Γ╦σl╚\020.αd∙
\001               Æ│T~\022ô≡σ.\017╤\024     e.t             n.f              S\034╢ßáσºE.0\023╢         δ╤\002ìu\a|₧.╚─╟
\001               \025╒æ\016!\026w┌.└_¬     e.t             np┼(ªxπº.⌠\004       ƒ)╕ßùl_s.ñ╕\031        ε\003
\001               a.f           èu5»$ε⌡S.4ºv        n.t              ß·╓▌;█Ü┌.\fδ╗          ε\003
\001.,\001\v           a.f           êvUè÷,Ü╝.╝╔\n       +N\002t\002∙S╖.▄V\003    ▓\035ß=▄Γp».:║5        \\╔ε╨\bε_\b.#n▀
\001.,\001\v           ╓;*·╔\025\017à.í]$    ëx\030`m\022╛£.╟|æ  nvoker".uiA          s.t                Θ\003
\001.,\001\v           ≥╪\t»╜√▀a.ìvm         é¿&zΘ╓\nó.▄7æ       ╜─┐nδ.╕\030.ô╠\177   stInfo>∙ú.¬Ñ\016        \003
╖0├0»0             \022B■#▌e╥ó.i)\a      i.2             \006¿ó±╪\177n\005.%cφ    *ü\020\r\023╜╦╪.ñ\033\v     $2f\t┤₧≈.α╡\032
0.4            ╡BJô\r≈}⌠.╝╫=         =≥(»i\035|┬.4cA     \ròo\0054?7`.╛"ñ     ╧\025ù@/⌠>o.e|9        \n.  
└¼\026\005ä-t_.{       b.p           ╥ia╩!3╜Γ.δyσ        Ö\001╬öΘáⁿ"."≥╥      u±ò\022"╦\f".@?v         Ç
\ 0¿│\006▐ba.⌠▐\\      \022b└u≤i┐─.|▌╟       ibility>..\035ï{    "\ manife.stv       \b.s             yToken=".659             é
a              ,Éä╝┘┘Y\t.ne8         m─f}ï\004É\020      \b.s             ÿ\016╧░Θ\024u\033.╫v╘        é
\001.a             \006êb'╪╜ß╞.{╛æ       mkx├å½ûΩ.u\017\002  \b.s             z1ÿß9εσs.╒¡¢           \025.  é
\020.A\001\001         ecurity>.7           :êh╗Z╜+\020.\022lf    ╓\032/m.\006w╥      schemas-.mic         Zr]¬6N_½.X▄·
Ä7ï\032íQF≥.\025s\177  e╚ï^,!@¬.9½ò      mw┬:╪ε\036ƒ.╓\021æ  s.e              z\177\037zê╤┌s.±;─
ª\ █*¬#=â.╨╨·          ┼╢\031ë∩¡$≤.─îî       m\033δ├2┌\vÄ.b∩.    s.e              α├4ÇX\f⌡≡.#7\037
ä¬\025ä4^$\n.─\016é    é≈╘m\n¢\016┐.è\177╚   mΩ·«æ╖┐┤.╚\177δ     s.e              \177αçhº\003▌▐.╘qπ
a║\037╔à8Jx.┴æ╜        ±«ëñ╥ì\t■.#≈┌         n..             s.e              αép|ä╙\034^.z╗¼
```

I can't delete anything. Help (?)

Comment: Looks like you might have corrupted your USB stick. Is there anything important on it, or can you just reformat it? (Also, I'd never heard of `dir` before. I always use `ls`, but they seem like the same.)

Comment: I believe that you corrupted your data, you should do a clone of the disk with `dd`, and try to recover your data. @Sparhawk `dir` is the `ls` of windows ;)

Comment: unicode character in volume or folder name that isn't handled properly is my guess.  if you don't have anything horribly confidential on there, just dd a copy to an image and attach it to a bug report.

Comment: 1) What makes you think this is malware rather than malfunction? 2) What filesystem are you running? 3) What does `dmesg` show you after plugging in, mounting it and showing the contents? 4) Have you tried running a filesystem check on the flash drive? 5) Are you sure the flash drive is still working properly (run some disk checks)? 6) How does the contents look in the GUI/Nautilus?

Comment: @Braiam Ah˙apparently `dir` is an alias of `ls -C -b`. http://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands

Comment: I'm not sure if this is off-topic, as it's not a bug report, and even though the OP uses 13.10, I suspect this error could have occurred on any version. It seems to me to have bought about by premature removal of the USB device.