# "No such file or directory" when trying to remove a file, but the file exists?

Tags: rm

I am trying to remove a png image that was uploaded to my server via a PHP script. Whenever I try to delete it both through ftp and terminal, I get the error

```
No such file or directory
```

However, when I `ls` in the dir, the file is listed and it is also listed in my ftp client. I have tried creating a file with the same name and I end up getting two files with the same name.

I can open the file that supposedly does not exist, but I still can't remove it. I have also tried rebooting my server. Any ideas what may be the issue? I am running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu, but I don't think its a 32/64 bit issue. I should also note I have removed many other png files uploaded by the same PHP script.

Output for `ls -l`

```
total 224 
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 222838 May 13 04:14 qyxdshyikfr_fishing_timeout.png 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 272 May 14 06:54 upload.php
```

Output when trying to `rm`

```
rm: cannot remove ‘qyxdshyikfr_fishing_timeout.png’: No such file or directory
```

upload.php: http://pastebin.com/z87eypTY

Comment: Copy paste the output of `ls -l` from the directory, also the full `rm` command and its output..

Comment: @heemayl
total 224
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 222838 May 13 04:14 qyxdshyikfr_fishing_timeout.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        272 May 14 06:54 upload.php

rm: cannot remove ‘qyxdshyikfr_fishing_timeout.png’: No such file or directory

Comment: @DevinFrench please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: From which directory you are running the `rm` command ?

Comment: @heemayl from the same directory as the file

Comment: Try to run `sync` and check if the file is still there

Comment: Try execute: lsof /path/to/file/qyxdshyikfr_fishing_timeout.png if no results are found, after `lsof`, execute following and post here the output: strace -ttt -F -i -s 255 rm -f qyxdshyikfr_fishing_timeout.png

Comment: Output from strace http://pastebin.com/jW3AJ0Ke

Comment: Well, it really shows that `unlink can't find the file`. There is a chance, we have a FileSystem issue here. What FileSystem is running on your Ubuntu?

Comment: Anyway I would run `fsck -AR -t < FS name > -y` just to check if there are another errors of such type...

Comment: You could use Bash's "file name completion" to generate the correct file name starts with `q`.  If that fails, it means the first letter isn't `q` but you can then use `rm -i *timeout.png` to remove it, or minor variations on the theme.  All this assumes this is a one-off problem and not a systemic one.

Comment: @Samuel Why would this suggest a filesystem problem? The `unlink` call will always fail to find a file that doesn't exist. When I run that `strace` command on *my* system, where I know I have no such file, it produces similar output; I don't think that indicates *I* have a filesystem problem! It seems far more likely that the file's name is slightly different from `qyxdshyikfr_fishing_timeout.png` and merely appears the same due to limitations in the way `ls` displays filenames, as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I have tried creating a file with the same name and I end up getting two files with the same name.

That says, absent filesystem corruption, that you have two files *with two different names* that *appear the same* because of non-printing characters or characters that look the same in your character set/font.  The `--escape` option to `ls` is your friend in such instances, as are tools such as `cat -v`.

So, too, is `rm -i -- *`

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/
- http://opensourceforu.com/2010/12/secure-upload-methods-in-php/

Comment: I was the creator of the file and the file name that was uploaded. No one was trying to sabotage my server as I am the only person that knows the complete path to upload.php
However, `rm -i -- *` did the trick.

Comment: @DevinFrench If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the mark under the upvotes count, so that future users might be aware of the fact that this solution worked for you.

Comment: Can someone explain `rm -i -- *` command?

Comment: From what I understand:
Passing `-i`  will prompt you before removal of each file. `--` before `*` selects all files regardless of whether their names include special characters. Reference: [https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rm+-i+--+*](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rm+-i+--+*)

Comment: `rm -i -- *` was ineffective.  Although I was asked to confirm deletion of each item.  On affirmation, `rm: cannot remove '_index.txt~': No such file or directory`.  Nevertheless, the file is `cat`able.

Answer (score 16):

***TL;DR:*** Run `ls -1b`, find the filename, copy the line on which it appears, and give that to `rm`.

As others have suggested, most likely this is due to limitations in the way `ls`--and some other programs, including client and server software--handle weird filenames, such as those containing control characters, by default. Your success with [JdeBP's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/623591/22949) strongly suggests this was the case, though it would've been a good bet even before that.

- For `ls`, when [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is a terminal, `?` characters are printed in their place. So if you're not piping `ls`'s output to any other command (or redirecting it to a log for viewing), probably your filename doesn't contain control characters. But there are other problematic characters--perhaps the filename contains trailing whitespace, for example.

  This behavior of `ls` can be confusing but is not a bug, can can be overridden explicitly by the user (see below).
- When attempting to access or remove a file remotely, bugs in client *or* server software can produce such problems.

  **I've experienced this sort of thing via `ftp` myself several times**, including for files whose names contain trailing spaces. (That it didn't work was due to a bug in my ftp client.) Even when you manually create a file yourself, depending on how you are creating it, it's sometimes quite easy to inadvertently insert a trailing space, or other whitespace that may look like spaces even though it isn't.

This is a situation where `ls -1b` (or [`dir -1`](https://askubuntu.com/a/615946/22949)) comes in handy:

- `-1` tells `ls` to show one entry per line. That way there is no confusion about where one filename ends and another begins. This is handy for weirdly named files.
- `-b` tells `ls` to print escape sequences for any special characters. The output of `ls -b` can be copied and pasted literally into a command, *with no added quoting*: all problematic characters are already quoted in a way that causes the shell to recognize them as what they are.

There is only one caveat: if the last character on a line appears to be `\`, copy one character after that, since this means `\` is quoting a space.

You can run `ls -1b` just like that, or you can pass a shell glob pattern to it (e.g., `ls -1b qyx*`). Globbing may or may not find the file, depending on whether or not the control characters (or other weird characters) are present in the portion of the name appearing in the glob pattern.

Having copied the `\`-quoted version of the filename given to you by `ls`, you can paste this into a command. You don't have to modify it manually in any way. In your case, as you wish to delete the file, type `rm`, type a space, paste the line, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

*Further reading:*

- [10.1 `ls`: List directory contents](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#ls-invocation) in the [GNU coreutils reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/).
- [My answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/615946/22949) to [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands), which is very different from your question but touches heavily on issues of how `ls` (and `dir`) displays strange filenames.

Comment: Very cool `-b` thx =) and +1

Comment: Something I left out of OP was when I created a file with the same name, in my ftp client when I tried to delete the first file that I was having issues with, it would instead delete the new file that I made. That is why I didn't think any special characters were involved, and I still don't know what the special character was since I used `rm -i -- *`.

Comment: @DevinFrench The extra character is a space at the end of the file name.  It's still in the `ls` output in the question, but can only be seen in text mode when you click "edit".

Comment: @Izkata Good call! I should've thought to check that. It also appears when I expand revision 3 in [the edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/623577/revisions) (the full filename, including the trailing space, is highlighted in green and thus discernible). What you've said is the most definitive and specifically correct explanation so far--if you posted an answer explaining that it's from a trailing space, and how you know, and what command would remove the file (if the OP still had it), I know I'd upvote it.

Comment: @EliahKagan Done, with pictures

Comment: Someone's script has created '=\ ' file in my case... This helped me to figure out what the filename acutally was!

Answer (score 5):

So I had this problem and none of these things worked for me. What worked was creating a file with the exact same name. It was a folder named Example.1.2.3 so I created a new folder and named it the exact same as the one that wouldn't delete. The old folder disappeared and I deleted the new one.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `find` and check the output:

   If the file is not found, then shortening the search term `*qyxdshyikfr*` slightly, eg:  `*qyxds*` or `*fishing*`.

   ```
    sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*qyxdshyikfr*"
   ```
2. If ok, than use `find` with the search term in step 1 and `rm`

   ```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*qyxdshyikfr*" -print0 | xargs -0  rm
   ```

Comment: Rather than calling `rm` by name via a pipe from `find` to `xargs`, I recommend simply using `find`'s `-delete` action. Also `sudo` isn't needed. Less significantly, I suggest omitting `-type f` except where it's clearly helpful. Presumably if the entry the OP wants to delete turned out to be a symbolic link, for example, they'd still want to find it and still want to delete it. The `-delete` action won't recursively clobber a directory; neither will your `rm` command since you don't have `-r`. So you aren't going to accidentally whack a whole (non-empty) folder here by not using `-type`.

Comment: OK, give me a second.

Comment: In my case, even `find ... -delete` says "cannot delete ... No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Reposting in detail, expanded from my comment on Eliah's answer</sub>

The problem is invisible, but can be seen if you know what to look for:  The file name includes a space at the end.  Because you copy/pasted the entire `ls` output, it can be seen in the question if you highlight the output, or edit the post and move the cursor to the end, or (as Eliah pointed out) look at the diff in the edit history.  I highlighted the `ls` output in the post in this screenshot:

[image: Extra space]

A quick little terminal session to duplicate the problem, with comments:

```
$ touch 'foo '        # Create file with a space at the end
$ ls -l               # Space is not visible in ls output
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 izkata izkata 0 May 14 21:59 foo 

$ rm foo              # Cannot remove it when not specifying the space
rm: cannot remove ‘foo’: No such file or directory

$ rm 'foo '           # Can remove it if we quote the file name and include the space
$ rm foo\             # Or can escape the space to tell bash to include it as part of the filename
```

Using [tab completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) would have also completely sidestepped the problem here, as bash is smart enough to escape spaces correctly <sub>(It's also a good habit in general, speeds up typing paths so much)</sub>.

For example, had I typed `rm f<tab>`, it would have auto-completed to `rm foo\<space><space>`, as in the last example in the code block above.

Comment: I make special mention of copy/pasting the `ls` output because something similar happened on StackOverflow once (and is the whole reason I thought to look for this):  someone got a non-printable character in their code, and the only reason anyone figured it out is because that user also copy/pasted instead of re-typing their code when posting the question

Answer (score 0):

once, i've created a file to open Nautilus as root, but the file name when seeing from nautilus was "File Browser (root)", then when i tried to remove as

```
$ rm "File Browser (Root)"
$ sudo rm "File Browser (Root)"
$ sudo rm "File Browser (Root).desktop"
```

the only anwser i got was: "rm: cannot remove 'File Browser (Root).desktop': No such file or directory"

then when i run:

```
$ ls -l
```

i saw/remembered that the file name, in fact, was "Nautilus-root.desktop"

so i run:

```
$ sudo rm "Nautilus-root.desktop"
```

worked for me, hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, after using `rsync` to backup my *Pictures* directory on a Mac and reading it on Ubuntu.
There were two files (actually directories) with different names, but having the same content. I deleted one to the Trash (using Nautilus), but could not delete the other, even from the command line. It would say:

```
$ rmdir Pictures
rmdir: failed to remove 'Pictures': No such file or directory
$ rm Pictures
rm: cannot remove 'Pictures': Is a directory
```

After checking the inode numbers with ls -i -l it turned out that both directories have the same inode number. Looks like a hard link...

The solution was surprisingly simple - empty the Trash by right clicking on the icon. After that both directories were gone.