# File exists, but cannot be deleted

Tags: files

I have a file in a directory that exists:

```
# cat 0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78 
@root

es5
module

tabs
indent 2
maxlen 80

ass
nomen
plusplus
```

But when I try to delete it

```
# rm 0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78 
rm: cannot remove '0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78': No such file or directory
```

I tried the answers in
["No such file or directory" when trying to remove a file, but the file exists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623577/no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-remove-a-file-but-the-file-exists)
but they don't work. There don't seem to be any special characters.

```
# ls -1b
0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78
# ls -q
0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78
# find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*0f*"
./0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78
# ls -l
total 512
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 Nov 27  2015 0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78
# rm -i -- *
rm: remove regular file '0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78'? y
rm: cannot remove '0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78': No such file or directory
# ls --escape
0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78
```

What's going on here? Can someone help me remove this file?

EDIT: Output of `stat` command:

```
$ stat 0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78 
  File: '0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78'
  Size: 63          Blocks: 1          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 48177       Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-01-04 00:06:49.697084100 -0500
Modify: 2015-11-27 20:15:19.490769000 -0500
Change: 2017-01-17 23:01:34.343100100 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Other commands suggested:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*0f*" -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78’: No such file or directory
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*0f*" -exec stat {} +
  File: './0f7fe16ba45fda36462cb35f82ad8c64730e78'
  Size: 63          Blocks: 1          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 48177       Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-01-04 00:06:49.697084100 -0500
Modify: 2015-11-27 20:15:19.490769000 -0500
Change: 2017-01-17 23:01:34.343100100 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Comment: boot from a live CD and run fsck for the partition that has the file in question.

Comment: Can you stat the file and show us the output?

Comment: What The Pizza Overlord is saying, do `stat <filename>`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @jsalatas I'll try that if nothing else works; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @The Pizza Overlord  I've posted the output, but I can't make anything of it; hopefully it reveals something to you.

Comment: @Serg I've posted the output, thanks for clarifying about the `stat` command, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @muru I've pasted the output of what you asked too. The first one is giving an error..

Comment: @AdityaKashi should have been just `-delete` without the `-ok`, sorry: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*0f*" -delete`, but in any case, I think this is a situation where an `fsck` is warranted.

Comment: @muru Ran the corrected command. Okay, cool, thanks for your help! So this file is on a NTFS partition. I can just unmount it and run fsck right? Or do I need a live USB stick?

Comment: @AdityaKashi yes, unmounting should be enough. But `ntfsfix` for NTFS, not fsck

Comment: @AdityaKashi - Your stat output looks good to me. Aside from an inode allocation issue, I wouldn't be sure what to look at next. A file system check would be advisable, however. Out of interest, what happens when you try to interact with the file in any other way? So, renaming, for example using `mv`, or copying to another directory using `cp`.