# cannot delete a file that does exist

Tags: command-line, removing

I started copying a (large) file inside a python script with `copyfile` from [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) and I had to interrupt the transfer. Now I notice that I cannot delete the file

The file that I am trying to delete is shown below (i.e. it appears to exist)

```
ngs@bngs05b:/path/to/dir/210305_M05113_0148_000000000-J6HHR/Data> ll
total 1
-rwxrwx--- 1 user lgen 99542099  6. Mai 11:42 LHLA-MS5387-MJ-S-10_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

If I then try to remove it with `rm`

```
ngs@bngs05b:/path/to/dir/210305_M05113_0148_000000000-J6HHR/Data> rm LHLA-MS5387-MJ-S-10_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
rm: cannot remove 'LHLA-MS5387-MJ-S-10_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz': No such file or directory
```

which is a very strange behaviour in my opinion.

I tried a few solutions as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623577/no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-remove-a-file-but-the-file-exists) (e.g. `ls --escape`, `ls -1b`), but none of them work.

I also tried to see if that file was opened somewhere, though the output of `lsof +D` does not output anything useful I guess:

```
ngs@bngs05b:/path/to/dir/210305_M05113_0148_000000000-J6HHR/Data> lsof +D .
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF                NODE NAME
bash    44509  ngs  cwd    DIR   0,37        0 5429445751479423221 .
lsof    45768  ngs  cwd    DIR   0,37        0 5429445751479423221 .
lsof    45769  ngs  cwd    DIR   0,37        0 5429445751479423221 .
```

I first thought that the problem had something to do that the copied file was corrupt/ incomplete, though I don't think this is the case as I checked that the size of the file in the original location is the same of the file that I am trying to delete.

Does anyone know how can I get rid of this file?

Comment: it may cause because of a corrupt process! did you try reboot the system once then removing the file?

Comment: the directory is only mounted on a server, so I guess rebooting it is last resort

Comment: does `ls LHLA-MS5387-MJ-S-10_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz` give an error? and what does `ls LH` show when you use {tab} to complete the file? any extra characters?

Answer (score 0):

The filename might have some strange characters which you cannot see in the terminal.

If this is the only file in the data directory I would remove the data directory and take the file with it,

```
rm -rf data
```

otherwise try using a gui file manager to remove it or see if you can remove it with a wildcard pattern, use ls with the pattern first so that you ensure you remove the target :)

```
ls LHRA*.gz
```

if that lists your file then

```
rm LHRA*.gz
```

If it was in use by another process the message would be different.

Comment: it could have been yes that the file has weird characters that the terminal does not show, that's not the case though. Unfortunately I had already tried all of these commands and none of them work (considering the correct directory/ file names - Data and LHLA)

Comment: Sorry for the typos!  What message was returned from the rm -rf Data command?

Comment: I get `rm: cannot remove 'Data/': Directory not empty`