# Can open directory in file explorer but not in terminal

Tags: permissions, windows, nautilus, ntfs, ls

I have some files that I copied over to Ubuntu 22.04 from my old Windows system. I noticed that many of them were highlighted this strange green color, so following [advice from Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881949/ugly-color-for-directories-in-gnome-terminal) I recursively did `chmod 775` on all these directories.

Unfortunately that seems to have broken some stuff. In particular, there are a few folders that I cannot `ls` or `cd` into in the terminal. I get the error `ls: cannot access 'folder-name': no such file or directory`. But, strangely, I can open this directory and view the files no problem using Nautilus.

When I copied these files over from Windows I really should have made sure to convert them from NTFS to EXT4 format first. Lesson learned.

What should I do? Is there some way I can identify all the files that are in Windows format and convert them? Should I reinstall my operating system?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the file/folder name really `----` or is that a placeholder in your question? Please provide actual example of the command and output copied directly from the terminal to your question above followed by a screenshot of nautilus.

Comment: @user68186 Sorry yeah, that's just a placeholder. I am out of the house right now so I can't remember the precise name of the folder in question. But it only had letters and hyphens in it, no spaces

Comment: I actually just thought of a solution so dumb that it actually might work. Can I just drag and drop my entire filesystem onto Google Drive, and then re-download it? Won't that reset all the file formats and permissions back to their default values? I have unlimited Google Drive cloud storage so the space is not an issue.

Comment: That may work. "Drag and drop" reminded me of another solution. 1. Open Nautilus. 2. Open a terminal. type `ls ` or `cd `(note the space after the command). then drag and drop the file or folder into the terminal. It will generate the full path of the file or folder. Hit the **Enter** button to execute the ls or cd command. Add the command and the output to your question if you have problem.

Comment: @user68186 That's a really clever solution. I will try that out.