# Text file output of directory contents

Tags: files, text

My apologies if this has been asked before. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 desktop and would like to be able to output the contents (file names) of a directory into a single text file via terminal/cli.

I think when I used to use DOS, years back, went something like this: dir /w/p > file.txt
..think that was it, but simple and damn handy

Thank you for your time and help with my question

Answer (score 1):

The general command for listing directory contents in Linux is `ls`

```
LS(1)                            User Commands                           LS(1)

NAME
       ls - list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
       ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       List  information  about  the FILEs (the current directory by default).
       Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort  is  speci‐
       fied.
```

Probably the nearest equivalent to `dir /w` will be `ls -C` (the `/p` option - pause - doesn't really make sense when writing to a file). So

```
ls -C > file.txt
```

In fact, there's a `dir` command in Linux as well - so you could just do `dir > file.txt`

See [Difference between 'dir' and 'ls' terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands)

Comment: Thank you for your help steeldriver, appreciate it.  Very true about the /p option, just so use to using it to pause dir output. Take care and thank you again ;)