# How do I substitute "ls -l" with the same in "dir"?

Tags: command-line, ls

I'm using Ubuntu server using local access only SSH, but when I issue the `dir` command all I get is a single list of files and folders with no details, but using `dir -l` gives me the long list, but still nothing compared to using `ls -l` which shows colors corresponding with permissions, how do I get that same display using `dir`, without having to keep appending command line switches?  such as `dir -l`.

Previously, using `dir` would show the long list automatically, but over time and a multitude of updates, the automatic display of long list `dir` isn't there now.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an alias to .bashrc to tell the shell on the server to run `ls -l` whenever you type `dir`, basically, just the following line:

`alias dir='ls -l'`

Save and exit, then run `source .bashrc` to reload.

Comment: Always a pleasure :~)

Answer (score 1):

**If you're going to make `dir` an alias, I suggest `alias dir='dir --color=auto -l'`.** That is probably the behavior you are looking for. This has the benefit of maintaining the other aspects of how `dir` is different from `ls`, and of not relying or--nor even being affected--by any `ls` alias you might have.

You can define aliases and shell functions that have the same name as the name of an external command (like `ls` and `dir`), and they can be defined to call that external command with additional options passed to it. That's what the alias suggested above does. So perhaps you used to have a `dir` alias (or shell function) that ran `dir -l`.

[**When that *isn't* done, though, `dir` works like `ls -Cb`.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands) The `ls` and `dir` commands are different. The purpose of the `dir` command is to be a command like `ls` whose behavior is unaffected by whether or not it is being run in a terminal. For this reason, you might consider *not* making `dir` an alias at all, and simply using `ls` or `ll` instead. `ll` is a commonly defined alias for `ls -l`.

While alias expansion is not determined by whether or not the output is a terminal, it is determined mostly by whether or not the shell in which you run the command is interactive. (There are ways to override that, but usually you don't want to.) Furthermore, `--color=auto` colorizes only when the output device is a terminal, so that you don't get usually undesired color codes if you (for example) redirect the output to a file.

However, if you want to change what happens when you run `dir`, then the reason I suggest making it an alias of `dir --color=auto -l` is that this *adds* the options you're asking for, while still implicitly using `-C` and `-b`. The presence of `-C` is not important, since it's overridden by `-l`. `-C` means to display in columns, and `-l` means to display as a detailed list. It can't do both so it does whatever the *last* option you pass it tells it to do. But `-b` is still significant; it causes weird characters in filenames to be escaped, so that you can usually copy filenames shown into terminal commands without modification.

Of course, you could instead use `alias dir='ls -bl --color=auto'`. This will achieve the same effect (you needn't include `-C` as it is overridden by `-l` anyway, as explained above). Or at least it would have the same effect if you had no `ls` alias. Alias expansion is not fully recursive, which is why you can alias `ls` to a command that starts with `ls` (or `dir` to a command that starts with `dir`). But alias expansion nonetheless continues until either the result is not an alias or further expansion would produce a recursive cycle. Defining your `dir` alias *not* in terms of `ls` frees you from unexpected effects resulting from whatever `ls` may be aliased to.

**As for where to put the alias definition**, you certainly *can* put it directly in the `.bashrc` file residing in your home directory, as [mikewhatever suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026763/22949). In this case, that has the benefit that you already almost certainly have alias definitions for `ls` in that file, and you could put your `dir` alias near there. Your `.bashrc` file may even already have commented-out (with `#`) aliases that you can uncomment and use.

However, I suggest instead putting new alias definitions--the ones you write yourself--in `.bash_aliases`. The default `.bashrc` files in Ubuntu will source that file if it exists. That is, `.bashrc` usually contains:

```bash
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

If for some reason your `.bashrc` file doesn't have that, then you can add it (or just the lines that don't start with `#`, if you don't feel like reproducing the comments).